# How to generate custom page names in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I lost my old website's code and am trying to recreate a function I had created ages ago.

I have custom pages in my Wordpress blog: about, work, contact, news as well as posts and subpages.

I am trying to manipulate the value of `<h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>` to display those different page tiles for those pages and their children so that it would look something like this:

```
if( $show == 'name' )
{
    if( is_page('work') ) $output = 'Work';
    if( is_page('contact') ) $output = 'Contact';
    if( is_page('about') ) $output = 'About';
}
return $output;
```

And as for all the rest of the pages, I just want it to display the default site value so somewhere along the line there would be an

```
else $output = "Site Name";
```

So I kind of understand the logic because I have done it in the past but cannot remember how the syntax went.

Could anyone refresh my memory?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the following in your `functions.php` file:

```
function so20527793_sitename()
{
    $output = get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    if( is_page( 'work' ) )       $output = 'Work';
    if( is_page( 'contact' ) )    $output = 'Contact';
    if( is_page( 'about' ) )      $output = 'About';

    return $output;
}
```

Usage:

```
<h1 class="site-title"><?php echo so20527793_sitename(); ?></h1>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks diggy! If I want to parse a default string before each page name i.e. Page how would I add it to the function? I tried passing it as a parameter of output but it did not work. Also, if all children pages of Work or About need to have the same name, how do I make sure this happens? i.e. "Page Name: About". Thanks for your help

Comment: I have tried something like this (not including the default string before the title):   `if( is_page( 'work' ) || is_child('work') ) $output = 'My work';` But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did not get much help in the end so I had to figure it out by googling and combining functions. Here is the result:

```
function is_child($page_id_or_slug) {
global $post;
if(!is_int($page_id_or_slug)) {
$page = get_page_by_path($page_id_or_slug);
$page_id_or_slug = $page->ID;
}
if(is_page() && $post->post_parent == $page_id_or_slug ) {
return true;
 } else {
 return false;
  }
}

function Custom_PageName(){

    $output = get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    if (is_page('about') ||  is_child('about'))  $output = 'About title';
    if (is_page('work') ||  is_child('work'))  $output = 'Work Page';
    if (is_page('contact') || is_child('contact')) $output = 'Contact';


    return $output;
    }
```